# Using semantic-ui and angularjs to show a list of items with a divider

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I want to show a divided list using semantic-ui and angularjs with an ng-repeat but I cannot get the dividing line to display.

```
<div class="ui divided list" ng-repeat="dataset in datasets.results">
    <div class="item">
        <i class="map marker icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <a class="header">{{dataset.name}}</a>
            <div class="description">{{dataset.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do something similar without angularjs then the line does display.

I assume it is the following rule in the semantic.css that is hiding the line

```
.ui.divided.list .item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
```

Does the way that angularjs works mean that every item in the list is the 'first', and is there an approach to work around this?

Here is a jsfiddle with an example

http://jsfiddle.net/uUjTZ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you'd created a fiddle.

There are many ways to make dividers, for example:

```
<div class="ui divided list" ng-repeat-start="dataset in datasets.results">
    <div class="item">
        <i class="map marker icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <a class="header">{{dataset.name}}</a>
            <div class="description">{{dataset.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat-end />
```

Comment: Well, you are repeating the `ul`, not the `div.item`. As a result, you have many `ul`'s with one `div.item` in each - of course, every `.item` is `:first-child`, because it's the only one element in `ul`. Try moving ng-repeat down to `div.item`. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUjTZ/3/)

Comment: Thanks - I got confused about what was repeating. I thought it was the contents of the div (not including the actual div that contains the repeat)